# How to remove in PHP outer tags from a node

Tags: php, domdocument

I have the following html code:

```
$pageHTML = '<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="some class">
<header>Header</header>
<section>Section</section>
<footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>';
```

and I need to remove outer tags of the `<div>` keeping all its inner HTML inside of the `<body>`

If I try

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($pageHTML);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$bodyDivs = [];
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0]->childNodes as $bodyChild) {
    if($bodyChild->nodeName == 'div') {
        $bodyDivs[] = $bodyChild;
    }
}

if(count($bodyDivs) == 1) {
    foreach($bodyDivs[0]->childNodes as $divChild) {
        $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0]->appendChild($divChild);
    }
    $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0]->removeChild($bodyDivs[0]);
}
```

the div is being removed but without appending its childs to `<body>` before the removing

If I try a reverse loop like

```
$k = count($bodyDivs[0]->childNodes);
for($n = $k-1; $n >= 0; $n--) {
    $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0]->appendChild($bodyDivs[0]->childNodes[$n]);
}
$dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0]->removeChild($bodyDivs[0]);
```

the childs are being added to the body, but in reverse order

So I get

```
<body>
<footer>Footer</footer>
<section>Section</section>
<header>Header</header>
</body>
```

but I need

```
<body>
<header>Header</header>
<section>Section</section>
<footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

How to resolve the problem?

Comment: What you wrote is very confusing, maybe its a translation thing, but could you post as an update what you want `$pageHTML` to look like after doing this.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code is very close, just missing one key point.

**Original code**

```
foreach($bodyDivs[0]->childNodes as $divChild) {
    $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0]->appendChild($divChild);
}
```

Trying to `foreach` a list of nodes, while also removing nodes from that same list (in your case, moving them to the `<body>`), does not behave as you intended.

**Simplified, complete example** for demonstration purposes:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML('<example><a/><b/><c/><d/><e/></example>');
$parent = $doc->documentElement;
foreach ($parent->childNodes as $child) {
    $parent->removeChild($child);
}
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

This outputs the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<example><b/><c/><d/><e/></example>
```

Totally sensible, right?! Fear not, we can do better.

**What to do?**

A common approach, that does behave as intended, is to loop over the list until it is empty.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML('<example><a/><b/><c/><d/><e/></example>');
$parent = $doc->documentElement;
while ($parent->childNodes->length > 0) {
    $child = $parent->childNodes->item(0);
    $parent->removeChild($child);
}
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

**Applied to your code**

All of the above means that your original `foreach`:

```
foreach($bodyDivs[0]->childNodes as $divChild) {
    $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0]->appendChild($divChild);
}
```

Can be replaced with a while loop.

```
while ($bodyDivs[0]->childNodes->length > 0) {
    $divChild = $bodyDivs[0]->childNodes->item(0);
    $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->appendChild($divChild);
}
```

<sup>Aside: I used the `->item(0)` notation above, as that's more conventional.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found my own solution but maybe someone will post more elegant:

```
if(count($bodyDivs) == 1) {

    $count = count($bodyDivs[0]->childNodes);

    $arr = [];
    for($n = $count-1; $n >= 0; $n--) {
        $arr[] = $bodyDivs[0]->childNodes[$n];
    }

    for($n = $count-1; $n >= 0; $n--) {
        $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0]->appendChild($arr[$n]);
    }

    $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0]->removeChild($bodyDivs[0]);
}

echo str_replace("\n\r", "", $dom->saveHTML((new \DOMXPath($dom))->query('/')->item(0)));
```